# Issue with copying rows from the source sheet to the destination sheet on the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create a macro that can take data from a source sheet (will have the same format but will have different # of rows for every instance I run it) and will have to run it multiple times a day and copy the rows from that sheet to a specified location on the destination sheet.

The Source sheet has a column that is the driver for this exercise. Based on the value in this column, it will select all the rows with that same value and paste them on the destination sheet at the given location.

So for instance if that value is 1, it will take all rows with '1' and paste them on the destination sheet at say cell A23. If the value is 2, it starts pasting the rows at cell A44 etc.

I have most of the code below. The problem I am facing is that it pastes the rows in the given block BUT this code accounts for the header of the source table as well as any rows that are filtered by the logic.

So if there are 5 rows with parameter value =1, followed by another 4 with the parameter value 2, when it runs through the code, if the first block starts at cell A23, this will paste the 5 rows starting at cell A24 (excluding the first row for the header on the source sheet). For parameter value = 2, the code excludes the first 5 rows and starts pasting at row A50 since it accounts for the header and the 5 rows for parm 1. How can I make it exclude the rows that are filtered out?

Note: The issue I am having is with the Rows property but am unable to get it to filter those rows out...Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Sheets("SrcSheet").Range("E:E")
        If cell.Value = Sheets("DestSheet").Range("A20").Value Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("DestSheet").Range("A23").Rows(Cells.Row)
        ElseIf cell.Value = Sheets("DestSheet").Range("A41").Value Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("DestSheet").Range("A44").Rows(Cells.Row)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have tried multiple variations of the code but get the same result including using Copy Destination etc. but removing the Rows property only copies the last row per parameter even though it copies it at the right location.

[image] - This is the source sheet

[image] - This is the destination sheet with the expected results

[image] - this is the destination sheet with the actual results. As I have tried in my description above; the code skips one row in block 1 (for the header) and 5 rows in block 2 (for the header and the lines for actg line value 1)

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't do what you've said. It keeps overwriting all the values on A23 and A44. Is that what you want it to do? It's not clear what you mean by excluding rows, and filtering out... is one of your sheets filtered? It might be more clear if you show a sample of what you have in SrcSheet and what you want in DestSheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am attaching screenshots of the source and dest files. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Yes that makes it much more clear. I have updated my answer below using the `FILTER` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `FILTER` formula? In DestSheet, if A1 is "Block1", use this formula in A2:

```
=FILTER(SrcSheet!A:E,SrcSheet!A:A=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Block","")))
```

Comment: unfortunately my version of excel does not support the Filter function -- Excel 2016 Pro Plus.